# How to send Object data inside a event and how to get it back?

Tags: c#, listview, datagridview

I'm trying to drag and drop a data row values from a data grid to list. I have two events in order to do that. but how can i pass two values?

This is the grid event

```
private void dgv_Mapper1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //this works
    //dgv_Mapper1.DoDragDrop(dgv_Mapper1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value, DragDropEffects.Copy);

    //this is what i want, to send two values
    dgv_Mapper1.DoDragDrop(new { First = dgv_Mapper1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value, Last = dgv_Mapper1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value }, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

and this is list event
Problem is i don't understand how to access the object and get the two values.

```
private void list_Head1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //this works with one object          
    //list_Head1.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text.ToString().Trim()));
}
```

Comment: You'll never get anywhere as long as you use an anonymous type.  Declare a class first to store the data and create an object of it that you pass to DoDragDrop().  Now instead of DataFormats.Text which you know cannot possibly work, you can use typeof(classname) in your DragEnter and DragDrop event handlers.

Comment: Sample code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1823546/17034), note the DragObject declaration.