# C# Drag and Drop delete

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, eventhandler

I was just wondering how I would go about Dragging an item from a list box and dropping it into an image that will then delete the value from the list box.
This is the code I have so far;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
textBox1.AllowDrop = true;
pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
}

private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

{
if ( listBox1.Items.Count > 0 )
    listBox1.DoDragDrop(    /* ? */      , DragDropEffects.Move);    //This 
statement is incomplete!
}

private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)

{
e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)

{
//Code to copy selected List Box entry to Text Box and remove original entry
}

private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)

{
e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
//Code to remove selected entry from List Box
}
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Many thanks

Comment: Is this Winforms?

Comment: Yes it is, visual studio

Comment: Just pass the ListBox object itself.  In the DragDrop event handler you can get it back and know that, since it is a ListBox and not (say) a file from Explorer, the sensible thing to do is to remove the selected item.  Do improve the DragEnter event handlers.  Additional code is required to make MouseDown work correctly, you do not want to lose the ability to select items.  Sample code [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823546/17034).